# How to use Generic Kafka Consumer in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, dependency-injection

I'm trying to make a generic implementation of kafka consumers in .NET. Basically I don't want to have a consumer for each and every type of message. I want a generic consumer and then the logic of handling the message is in actual Handlers.

What I tried:

Create a generic interface for handlers

```cs
public interface IKafkaHandler<TKey, TMessage>
{
    Task HandleAsync(TKey key, TMessage message);
}
```

Create a concrete handler

```cs
public class ClubMessageHandler : IKafkaHandler<string, ClubMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ClubMessageHandler(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task HandleAsync(string key, ClubMessage message)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Let's go {message.Name}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Create a generic consumer

```cs
public class GenericConsumer<TKey, TMessage> : BackgroundService
    where TKey: class
    where TMessage : class
{
    private readonly IKafkaHandler<TKey, TMessage> _handler;

    public GenericConsumer(IKafkaHandler<TKey, TMessage> handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        var conf = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            GroupId = "st_consumer_group",
            BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
        };
        using (var builder = new ConsumerBuilder<TKey, TMessage>(conf).Build())
        {
            builder.Subscribe("topic.name");
            var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var consumer = builder.Consume(stoppingToken);
                    //here I want to inject the correct handler based on TMessage type
                    _handler.HandleAsync(consumer.Message.Key, consumer.Message.Value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                builder.Close();
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And this is where I kinda got stuck. If I try in Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKafkaHandler<string, ClubMessage>, ClubMessageHandler>();
```

I get an exception saying it can't resolve the services (I can post the entire message if needed)

In the end what I want to achieve is to be able to have something like

```cs
//Inject Handlers
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKafkaHandler<string, ClubMessage>, ClubMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKafkaHandler<string, PlayerMessage>, PlayerMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IKafkaHandler<string, OtherMessage>, OtherMessageHandler>();

//Start background services
builder.Services.AddSingleton<GenericConsumer<string, ClubMessage>, ClubMessageHandler>();
//etc...
```

At this point I'm not even sure if this is possible(although it probably is)? I'm not really sure what I'm missing here. What's the correct way to have use dependency injection here?

Comment: Should you just call `Services.AddHostedService<GenericConsumer<string, ClubMessage>>()` instead of `Services.AddSingleton<GenericConsumer<string, ClubMessage>, ClubMessageHandler>()` or am I misunderstanding what you want to know.

Comment: There are btw other suggestions to make about the `GenericConsumer` implementation, but that probably goes beyond the format of Stack Overflow.

Comment: You're not setting a deserializer anywhere? What does your producer code look like for sending multiple event types?

Comment: Take a look at KafkaFlow (https://github.com/Farfetch/kafka-flow). He does precisely that.